# Jump sizes of a compound Poisson process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I have a Poisson process $(S_t)$ defined by
$$S_t  = \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} Z_i$$
where $Z_t$ are i.i.d. standard normals, and $N_t$ is a Poisson process. I have to determine

1. the set of all possible jump sizes
2. the distribution of the waiting time until the first jump $T_1 := \inf \{t>0 : S_t \neq 0 \}$
3. moment generating function of $S_t$

In the first problem I do not know how to define "all possible jump sizes".

The second problem I start with
$$F_{T_1} (y) = P(T_1 \leq y) = P(\inf \{t>0 : S_t \neq 0 \}\leq y) $$
But then again, have no idea how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you are summing over $Z_i$ (and not $Z_t$). To get a better intuition about the jumps, you might want to draw a picture ... how does a realization of a sample path $t \mapsto S_t$ look like? Just pick some numbers, say $Z_1(\omega)=5$ and $Z_2(\omega)=-3$ for a start.

Comment: @saz, Could it be that the jump is $\bigtriangleup Y_t = Z_{N_t} \cdot N_t$?

Comment: No, that's not correct. This would mean that the (absolute) jump height would be getting larger with increasing time... which is not the case. Did you follow my suggestion to draw the graph?

Comment: Yes I drew it. Small mistake: the formula $\bigtriangleup Y_t = Z_{N_t} \cdot \bigtriangleup N_t$ seems to be correct now? Does this now mean that the set of all possible jumps is $\{Z_{N_t} \cdot \bigtriangleup N_t : t \geq 0\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. What do you know about the jumps of the Poisson process? Which height do they have? This will allow you to simplify the expression which you obtained.

Comment: They have the height 1. Therefore $\{Z_{N_t} : t \geq 0\}$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that's right. For Part 2 you can take again a look at your graph. When does the first jump happen? (... and to answer part 2 you will also need to take into account what you know about the first jump time of the Poisson process)

Comment: My attempt would be $$P(\inf\{ t>0 : S_t \neq 0\} \leq y) = P(\inf\{ t>0 : Z_{N_t} \neq 0 \text{ and } \bigtriangleup N_t \neq 0\} \leq y) = P(\inf\{ t>0 : \bigtriangleup N_t \neq 0\} \leq y)$$ and the latter is exponentially distributed, so I think I am allowed to do $$P(\inf\{ t>0 : \bigtriangleup N_t \neq 0\} \leq y) = P(\bigtriangleup N_t \neq 0: 0 < t \leq y) $$ I would need one more hint from here on, if possible. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your first computation shows that $T_1$ has the same distribution as the first jump time of the Poisson process. You say yourself that the latter has exponential distribution. Hence, what is the distribution of $T_1$? For part 3: Write $$S_t = \sum_{k \geq 1} 1_{\{N_t =k\}} \left( \sum_{i=1}^k Y_i \right)$$ and use the independence of $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(Y_i)_{i \geq 1}$.

Comment: @saz I get
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[e^{\theta S_t}] &= \mathbb E\left[e^{\theta\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathsf 1_{\{N_t=k\}}\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i}\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[e^{\theta\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathsf 1_{\{N_t=k\}}}\right]\mathbb E\left[e^{\theta\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i}\right]\\
&= \mathbb E[e^{\theta(1-\mathsf 1_{\{N_t=0\}})}] e^{k^2\theta^2/2}\\
&= e^\theta\mathbb E[e^{-\theta\mathsf1_{\{N_t=0\}}}]e^{k^2\theta^2/2}\\
&= e^{k^2\theta^2/2+\theta} e^{-\theta}\mathbb P(N_t=0)\\
&=e^{k^2\theta^2/2+\theta} e^{-\theta}e^{-\lambda t}\\
&= e^{k^2\theta^2/2-\lambda t}.
\end{align}
Is this correct?

Comment: @Math1000 No, the second "=" is wrong. (A "sanity" check: For $t=0$ we have $S_0 =0$ and so $\mathbb{E}e^{\theta S_t}=1$ for all $\theta$... this property is not satisfied for the function which you got as final result.)

Comment: I don't see how else to use the independence of $N_t$ and $Y_i$ though.

Comment: I've now reached
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[e^{\theta S_t}] &= \mathbb E\left[e^{\theta\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathsf 1_{\{N_t=k\}}\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i}\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[e^{\theta(1-\mathsf 1_{\{N_t=0\}})\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i}\right]\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb E[e^{\theta(1-\mathsf 1_{\{N_t=0\}})Y_i}]\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^k\mathbb E[e^{\theta(1-\mathsf 1_{\{N_t=0\}})Y_1}]\\
&= \mathbb E[e^{\theta(1-\mathsf 1_{\{N_t=0\}})Y_1}]^k,
\end{align}
but I don't see how to proceed.